# Number of ways to distribute n different toys among n children so that any one child gets no toy

Tags: combinatorics

> Number of ways to distribute $n$ different toys among $n$ children so that any one child gets no toy ?

I tried using "star and bar method" and deduced that i need to calculate the number of arrangements possible for the string "$111...20$" where there are ($n-1$) different $1$'s, one $0$ (since $1$ child gets no toy), one $2$ (because $1$ child gets $2$ toys).

However, I'm not being able to reach the final answer. Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both the toys and the children are distinguishable, so this is not a stars and bars problem: it would be a stars and bars problem if the toys were indistinguishable.

HINT: There are $n$ ways to choose the child who is to receive no toy. There are $\binom{n}2$ ways to form a pair of toys to be given to the lucky child, and there are $n-1$ ways to choose who is to get that pair. Now there are $n-2$ single toys to be distributed to the remaining $n-2$ children so that each gets one toy. Can you put the pieces together now to come up with the final result?

Comment: Is the answer n(n-1)(n-2)! (n)C(2) ?

Comment: @Sanchayan: It is indeed, and that can be simplified to $n!\binom{n}2$.

Comment: @Sanchayan: You’re welcome!